# how can I add a background color to a header column label

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I need to add a background color that should be like this [image]

I think that the only solution would be to add a span inside the th container like this:

```
<th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Companies: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">
<span>Companies</span>
</th>
```

Unfortunatly I have no idea of how to add the spans

Answer (score 3):

Add this `bgcolor` attribute in `<th>` like this:

```
<th bgcolor="#FF0000">Companies</th>
```

Comment: Yes, but this will give the entire `<th>` a certain background color, not just the caption. OP seems not to want the arrow to have the same background color as the caption.

Answer (score 3):

You can include `<span>`'s in the `columns` / `columnDefs` `title` option :

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    columns: [
       { data: "name", title: '<span class="red">Name</span>'  },
       { data: "position", title: '<span class="blue">Position</span>' },
       //etc
   ]
})
```

examples -> **http://jsfiddle.net/z1afh42j/**

Comment: and it works like magic!! thanks for your fast and complete answer